# To do list using react-sortable-hoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-sortable-hoc

I'm using sortable drag and drop which works fine. The problem is that I'd like users to be able to remove items. The SortableItem component isn't accessible as it came with the code, so I can't pass an event handler that takes index as an argument. Here's what I have so far:

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(
 ({value}) =>
 <ul>{value}</ul>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
 return (
<ul>
  {items.map((value, index) => (
    <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
  ))}
</ul>
);
});

export class BlocksContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
  items: [],
 };
}
onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
  this.setState({
    items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex),
  });
};

addBlock = (block) =>{
  let arr = [...this.state.items, block];
  this.setState({items: arr})
}

removeBlock = (index) => {
let remove = [...this.state.items];
remove.filter(block => block === index);
this.setState({items:remove})
}

render() {
  return (<div><div onChange={console.log(this.state)} className="sortableContainer"><SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} /></div>
  <h2>Blocks</h2>
  <button onClick={() => this.addBlock(<BannerImage remove={this.removeBlock} />)}>Banner Image</button>
  <button onClick={() => this.addBlock(<ShortTextCentred remove={this.removeBlock}/>)}>Short Text Centred</button>
  <h2>Layouts</h2>
  <hello />
         </div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have control over the events of the `SortableItem` component, you can wrap that component in a component you do have control over.

For example, if i wanted to add a click handler to the `SortableItem`, i would add it instead to the div wrapper:

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <div onClick={this.someEventHandler}>
          <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, that's helpful. Do you know what would be the best way to remove an item using an event handler? Sortable list is defined outside of the class so I'm not sure how to update the state. I'm also not sure how to target a specific item when removing if I can't use index. If I used IDs then the ID would have to be dynamically generated when the user adds an item.

Comment: You can send the index to any event handler function like so: `onClick={() => { this.someEventHandler(index); }}` Then in your someEventHandler function you can remove it by deleting the index from `items` by `items.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: It throws an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeBlock' of undefined'. Because the div is defined outside of the class, it's outside the scope of the event handler. I can't move the event handler out of the class because then it won't be able to update the state.

Comment: Events handlers and almost all your code should be inside the class